# Java - Howto create a module menu strip or navigation bar

Tags: java, menustrip

I notice all my forms share the same menu strip with same menu items..

I want to create just one menu strip which can be imported into all my forms, so if I need to change/add/delete any items on that menu strip, I only need to do it once, rather going to all forms...

I am using netbeans ide..

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: 1-  Make use the Actions API; 2- Either create a factory that can generate the menu bar or create a custom JMenuBar class that you can then instantiate where you need it

Comment: Can you provide some example code